# Insert new line in NSTextFieldCell

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, newline

When writing a string to a NSTextFieldCell, I try to write "\n" but they get ignored and appear on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

add

```
textfield.numberOfLines = 0;
```

then use \n.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting a line break mode on the cell?

```
[yourCell setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
```